# PHP Spreadsheet color not working

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am trying to apply collors to my cells using a function which is this:

```
function color($cell, $color, $find = true){
        if ($find){
            $color = $this->color_helper($color);
        }

        $this->sheet->getStyle($cell)->getFill()->applyFromArray(array(
            'type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
            'startcolor' => array(
                'rgb' => $color
            )
        ));
    }
```

colors are defined in the color_picker function and they return something like ''FF0000'for red.

Now the problem is, after I download the file, nothing is changed, its like the original file.

Comment: did you save your changes?

Comment: I think I did, here is my code for that. https://pastebin.com/8A0hzXRU